# Is it safe to cast an unmodifiable Collection<? extends T> to Collection<T>

Tags: java, generics

I'm working with an old API that has a method that returns Collection<? extends T>; the API says the returned result is unmodifiable. It's considered bad form to return a bounded wildcard according to *Effective Java*. I've implemented a wrapper function so new code looks clean. It does

```
    Collection<? extends T> c0 = oldAPI();
    Collection<T> c = (Collection<T>)c0; // "unchecked cast" warning
    return c;
```

Is the cast "safe" in all situations? Most? If not, what's an example?

It seems like the cast is safe, and with limited testing things work as expected. A `@suppressWarnings("unchecked")` avoids a warning.

Perhaps what makes it safe is that the returned collection is unmodifiable.

Comment: why not create a new using the constructor that receives a collection?
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(c0);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* safe because the collection is unmodifiable.  That said, there is a neat and simple way to take advantage of that:

```
Collection<T> c = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(c0);
```

...which actually enforces the unmodifiability and allows you to upcast in that way.

Comment: Feels like the first time I've really looked at the "Collections.unmodifiable*" signatures. Thanks.